# Broadcastreceiver "Win Death"

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am doing some tests and I think Android is killing my remote Broadcastreceiver.

Right now I am starting my Broadcastreceiver from an activity and then having the broadcastreceiver set an alarm every minute to start itself again. This works great for a few hours (2-20 hours), then it gets "win death".

Does anyone know why I am getting this and what I can do to have it running permanently?

```
D/ShutMeUp AlarmReceiver(16161): ALARM TRIGGERED <br>
I/ShutMeUp AlarmReceiver(16161): Doing AWESOME stuff
<br>I/ShutMeUp AlarmReceiver(16161): Month:May Day:Monday Hour:0 Min:10
<br>D/ShutMeUp AlarmReceiver(16161): ALARM END
<br>D/ShutMeUp AlarmReceiver(16161): ALARM TRIGGERED
<br>I/ShutMeUp AlarmReceiver(16161): Doing AWESOME stuff
<br>I/ShutMeUp AlarmReceiver(16161): Month:May Day:Monday Hour:0 Min:11
<br>D/ShutMeUp AlarmReceiver(16161): ALARM END
<br>I/ActivityManager( 1904): Exiting application process se.davidsebela.ShutMeUp  
 (android.os.BinderProxy@4423b0b0)
<br>I/WindowManager( 1904): WIN DEATH: Window{4430bea8se.davidsebela.ShutMeUp/se.davidsebela.ShutMeUp.ShutMeUp paused=false}
<br>I/WindowManager( 1904): WIN DEATH: Window{441f17e8 se.davidsebela.ShutMeUp/se.davidsebela.ShutMeUp.Create paused=false}
<br>I/ActivityManager( 1904): Process se.davidsebela.ShutMeUp:remote (pid 16161) has died.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved my problem with `setRepeating()`

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), delayInMilli, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Activity life cycle]

You're maybe in the case "Apps with higher priority need memory" -> "app process killed".

With Linux you can't be sure an app running permanently.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If your code starts the broadcast-receiver from the activity you must also stop it (and the alarmmanager-entry) from activity, too because android might throw out your activity from memory as you experienced.</strike>

I register in `onResume()` and deregister in `onPause()`.

If you want your BroadCastReceiver to get reloaded if it thrown out of memory i would prefer to register the BroadCastReceiver through the manifest. In this case the android os handels loading/unloading.

[update]

```
 > I am starting my Broadcastreceiver from an activity
```

I misinterpreted this statement that you where registering the BroadCastReceiver by code instead of manifest. if it is registered in the manifest android takes care of loading the Broadcastreceiver code. so your problem is something different.

Comment: I am not hudred procent sure what you mean, I think I have the receiver in the manifest as you sugest.  <receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>
How could I restart the receiver if android kills it?

Comment: With starting from an activity I mean Intent intent = new Intent(Create.this, Alarm.class);
        sendBroadcast(intent);